# Why aren't there 2 newlines, when Python says there are 2 newlines?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tomcat7, hexdump

I have a bit of text I'm fetching from a web API, and it's confounding me trying to use Python to split paragraphs on double newlines.

Here's the smallest sample of the intriguing text:

```
>>> print my_string
e

N
```

Looks like 2 newlines, and Python agrees:

```
>>> print my_string.count('\n')
2
```

Trying to replace the newlines with another delimiter.  I'm expecting `eaaN`:

```
>>> print my_string.replace('\n', 'a')
aN
```

Weird.  Here's the text in hex:

```
87654321  0011 2233 4455 6677 8899 aabb ccdd eedff  0123456789abcdef
00000000: 650a 0a4e                                 e..N
```

I'm new to looking at something in hex, but I see two `0a` characters where I expect them, with no other control characters (so no CRLF wonkiness).

Is there something in the text or Python's interpretation of them that I'm missing?

As a control, I typed up the same string in Idle and tried the same functions:

```
my_string = """e

N"""
>>> my_string.count('\n')
2
>>> my_string.replace('\n', 'a')
'eaaN'
```

The web API is Tomcat's JMX interface.  Here's the path I'm using to query the API (and I know it's URI-escaped, but that's fine):

```
manager/jmxproxy?qry=Catalina:j2eeType=WebModule,name=//localhost/*,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none
```

Thank you.

**Solution**

They are CRLF's:

```
>>> print repr(my_string)
'e\r\n\r\nN'
```

I duped myself by "copying-pasting" the text from the interpreter to Emacs, where I did the hex analysis.  Writing to a file and then opening in Emacs showed me the error of my ways.

Comment: What does `repr(my_string)` look like?

Comment: Use `repr(my_string)` to have Python show you a string representation with newlines shown as escape sequences.

Comment: And how did you obtain the hex dump? Python does translate newlines from and to native line endings when dealing with files in text mode, so you may inadvertently have destroyed evidence somewhere.

Comment: @MartijnPieters looks like `python whatever | xxd`

Comment: Thank you @Wooble and @MartijnPieters, I'll use `repr()` in the future.

Comment: Either use `print(my_string)`, or in the interpreter prompt, just `my_string` would also echo the `repr()` result. :-)

Comment: @ZacharyYoung Can you post your solution as an answer?  Thanks :)